# iOS 6 - HTML encoded entities are not showing

Tags: html, iphone, ios, ios6, character-encoding

I am trying to show following HTML encoded form of string in UI.

```
 &#12402;&#12423;&#18780; &#22988;&#31078;&#27247;&#12397;&#35086; &#12428;&#12378;&#12375;&#12421;&#12366;&#12421;&#31299; &#12386;&#12423;&#31784;&#12445;&#12376;&#27695; &#33519;&#18147;&#34788; &#35253;&#12384;&#30440;&#43278;&#25315; &#22831;&#12386;&#12419;&#28975;&#22501;&#27045; &#26958;&#12409;&#26970; &#22377;&#12389;, &#35212;&#12403;&#12423; &#12399;&#18846;&#12403;&#12386;&#12376;&#12423; &#27687;&#12408;&#12532;&#12455;&#26660;&#20774; &#12386;&#12421;&#22823;&#24297; &#12407;&#35557; &#30986;&#18152;&#12395;&#12423; &#35174;&#32166;&#21347;&#26956;&#18997; &#12364;&#26919;&#12426;&#12421;&#27139;&#39500; &#34789;&#12446;&#30565;&#30437;&#18979; &#39436;&#25455; &#39529;&#12366;&#12423;&#12385;&#12421; &#12524;&#12444;&#14943;&#12459;&#12464;&#12457;&#38542; &#29482;&#20207;&#22762;&#40680;&#12470; &#12428;&#12378;&#12375;&#12421;&#12366;&#12421;&#31299;, &#12362;&#18690; &#12404;&#12421;&#12395;&#12421;&#18915;&#37864;&#20197; &#12467;&#12374;&#12385;&#12419;&#14372;&#12472;&#12519; &#33512;&#19503;&#12362;
```

Using this [library](https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWFeedParser/blob/master/Classes/NSString+HTML.h), I wrote following code

```
#import "NSString+HTML.h"
NSLog(@"%@",plainText);           
NSLog(@"%@",[plainText stringByDecodingHTMLEntities]);
```

On executing code, I am getting following exception:

```
    -[__NSCFString stringByDecodingHTMLEntities]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7bd4200
     *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 

'-[__NSCFString stringByDecodingHTMLEntities]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7bd4200'
    *** First throw call stack:
    (0x1caa012 0x10e7e7e 0x1d354bd 0x1c99bbc 0x1c9994e 0xa72d 0x4a0e53f 0x4a20014 0x4a107d5 0x1c50af5 0x1c4ff44 0x1c4fe1b 0x1c047e3 0x1c04668 0x2bffc 0x237d 0x22a5 0x1)
    libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

**Note:** I also tested my HTML encoded string on [this](http://www.webtoolhub.com/tn561387-html-encoder-decoder.aspx) link and found no errors in my string format.

Comment: Your error message shows that there is no `stringByDecodingHTMLEntities` method in your project.

Comment: but I imported on NSString+HTML.h and also on clicking on that function I go to NSString+HTML.h class

Comment: #import "NSString+HTML.h" where necessary .....

Comment: yes I already imporeted "NSString+HTML.h"

Comment: is that correct that I have to install GTMXcode4Plugin.xcplugin plugin, if yes then how can I do this?
and how can I add -fno-objc-arcas build flag to GTMNSString+HTML.m and NSString+HTML.m ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things were perfectly fine. All I needed was just to add compile source flag **`-fno-objc-arc`** by double clicking **NSString+HTML.m** and **GTMNSString+HTML.m** under Compile Source tab.

1. Just imported `NSString+HTML.m` and no need to import other class
2. Drag and drop **NSString+HTML.m** and **GTMNSString+HTML.m** in Compile Source tab first before adding flag.

Answer (score 0):

```
#import "NSString+HTML.h"
NSLog(@"%@",plainText);           
NSLog(@"%@",[plainText stringByDecodingHTMLEntities]);
```

You need add `NSString+HTML.h`, `NSString+HTML.m`, `GTMNSString+HTML.h`,  `GTMNSString+HTML.m` file to your project

```
add -fno-objc-arc
```

Build Phases -> Compile Sources -> select  GTMNSString+HTML.m -> double click right Compiler flags and add -fno-objc-arc

Comment: GTMNSString+HTML.m and NSString+HTML.m are not listed on compile source, but when i add these 2 classes manually it failed to build project